# Driver error bluetooth device Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, bluetooth

I recently bought a `Logitech MX Anywhere 2` mouse but suddenly after some days it started behaving incorrectly. It keeps working for a bit, then doesn't work anymore, then work again and so on every time. I tried everything, turning on/off the Bluetooth, removing and pairing the device, uninstalling and reinstalling Bluetooth drivers...

[image: Driver error]

I tried to search how to get a log file for this but nothing! I'm thinking to turn it back because maybe it's defected, but at least I'd like to know if it's actually defected or if it's because of my computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Logitech Options was messing with it. I just uninstalled it and it magically worked... I wonder how logitech can ship software that kills its devices. Jeez.